# Concat text around piped input with SED

Tags: linux, sed

Using SED on a pipe of input, how can i insert the input in the middle of text which will be used as a linux command?

```
 echo foobar | sed 's/^/one two /'
```

This will output `one two foobar`.

How can i use SED to reformat it so the piped value goes in between like `one foobar two`?

I already tried piping two SED commands in a row however this does not work and the formatting gets messed up. So im looking for a way to do it with a single SED command.

Comment: Use two `sed s` one for the start and one for the end: e.g. `echo foobar | sed 's/^/one /; s/$/ two/'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo foobar | sed 's/\(.*\)/one \1 two/'
```

Output:

```
one foobar two
```

Comment: Or, `echo foobar | sed 's/.*/one & two/'`

Comment: If the result is to be used as a command, and if on Linux, one may be intersted in sed `e` option, such as in `echo foobar | sed 's/.*/one & two/e'` (will run `one foobar two`).

Answer (score 0):

With `perl`

```
$ echo foobar | perl -lne 'print "one $_ two"'
one foobar two
```

- `-l` option strips newline from input line and adds it again to `print` statement
- `$_` default variable containing input line

Similarly with `awk`

```
$ echo foobar | awk '{print "one " $0 " two"}'
one foobar two
```

- The space around `$0` is optional and used for clarity